# POST to php and return page with posted data

Tags: php, post

i have a download.php file and an index.php file. I want download.php to post data to index.php and then show index.php in the browser window with the posted data inside of it. Is this possible? I thought i could use curl for this but that isn't working. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you request your own page if you may just `include` it?

Comment: I don't understand... Are you sending the user to index.php or are you trying to show the user index.php while keeping them on download.php?  And, if so, why?  Why not just post to index.php like normal?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, My curl code is

$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://stratus.sylentec.com/index');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $data = array(
            'stratus_code' => $keyword
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print $output;

which works fine but it doesn't seem efficient to post to another php file using curl if its on the same server. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong in your code ? You can use Curl.

Try this : http://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
//post the data
$.post('ajax/test.html',{ name: "test", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {

    //replace the .result div with the
    //response from the server
    $('.result').html(data);

});
```